# properly using exceptions while interating through lines python

Tags: python, file, exception

trying to write code that after a method is called the code will go through lines until it finds a line with only a number in it. then it will add that number to a amount. This is what I am thinking about I can't fully put my head around this.

```
 elif line == 'o' or line == 'O':
 amount = next(f)
            try:
                next(f)
            except TypeError:
                next(f)
            print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
            score.updateOne(amount)
```

so whats trying to be done is if a line contains the letter o then it is to go to the next line and add it to an amount. but if the amount is an empty space or a string. I need it to try and add the next line. if that doesn't work try the next until it finds the number and adds it to the line.

Online research has got me this far but can anyone else fill the gaps please?

thank you

just for a better understanding, here is the file that the code is trying to read:

50

O

30

O

40

M

10 20 30

o

5

m

1 2 3

X

and here is the code in the function that is using the class methods to execute tasks. I am not posting the class and its methods cause there is no point

```
score = Score() # initize connection
```

def processScores( file, score):

## opens file using with method, reads each line with a for loop. If content in line

## agrees with parameters in  elif statements, executes code in if statment. Otherwise, ignores line

```
with open(file,'r') as f:
    for line in f:  #starts for loop for all if statements
        line = line.strip()
        if line.isdigit():
            start = int(line)
            score.initialScore(start)
            print(line)#DEBUG TEST**** #checks if first line is a number if it is adds it to intial score

        elif len(line) == 0:
            print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
            continue        #if a line has nothing in it. skip it  

        elif line == 'o' or line == 'O':
            try:
                amount = int(line)
            except ValueError:
                continue
            else:
                score.updateOne(amount)
            amount =  next(f)
            print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
            score.updateOne(amount) #if line contains single score marker, Takes content in next line and
                                    #inserts it into updateOne

        elif line == 'm'or line == 'M':
            scoreList = next(f);next(f)
            lst = []
            for item in scoreList:
                print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
                lst.append(item)
                score.updateMany(lst) # if line contains list score marker, creates scoreList variable and places the next line into  that variable
                                      # creates lst variable and sets it to an empty list
                                      # goes through the next line with the for loop and appends each item in the next line to the empty list
                                      # then inserts newly populated lst into updateMany

        elif line == 'X':
            print(line)#DEBUG TEST****
            score.get(self)
            score.average(self) # if line contains terminator marker. prints total score and the average of the scores.
                                # because the file was opened with the 'with' method. the file closes after
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing:

```
try:
    next(f)
except ValueError:
    next(f)
```

you'll want to do the type conversion in the `try` block. For example:

```
for line in f:
    try:
        # try to convert the line to a number
        value = float(line)
    except ValueError:
        # oops! It wasn't a number... continue on with the next line.
        continue
    else:
        # good! It was a number, update the score.
        score.updateOne(value)
```

Your original code used `next` quite a bit to advance the iterator, but usually this is unnecessarily cumbersome. For example, your `next` calls will throw a `StopIteration` if you read the end of the file, and you haven't handled those in your code. A better way to is to take advantage of the fact that `f` can be iterated over (that is, assuming `f` is an open, file-like object), so writing `for line in f:` is all you need to do to loop over the lines of the file.

Now, your file has a special structure with `o` or `O` signaling an incoming value that you'd like to read. Here is some code that does just that:

```
total = 0
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for header in f:
        if header.strip().lower() == "o":
            for line in f:
                try:
                    value = int(line)
                except ValueError:
                    continue
                else:
                    total += value
                    break
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("No value found!")
```

This will throw a `RuntimeError` if your file is malformed, meaning it has an `o` that isn't followed by a value.

Comment: thank you. a quick question though, must I use float? or can I use Int instead?

Comment: @eatAllYourPiePeter You certainly can use `int`, if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: also I am not sure that works. Because I still need it to find the number after the 'o'

so something like this:

o (code thinks oh look an 'O' lets find a number)
'' (thats an empty space I cant do anything with that I need my number
5 (dude its a number. yay I need to add that to amount) 

and then of course press on with the other methods

thank you for your help man

Comment: @eatAllYourPiePeter Then you could use a state machine inside the loop. Keep the state in a variable and use an if/elif construct to act according to each state.

Comment: @eatAllYourPiePeter Ah, I missed that requirement. I added some code to do just that and avoid the use of `next` calls.

Comment: @jme I think its best I show you the entire code that uses the methods in the class. Because I already have the requirement. I will also post the file that the code is reading. The idea I am trying to do is once after finding the O the code adds the number it then moves on to the next elif statement. Let me show you. I have edited my original post

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you are trying to read file , If Yes then code should look something like

```
score = 0
with open('mydata.txt') as fp:
  for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):
     try:
         score += int(line)
     except ValueError as e:
         print "something is wrong with value "+e.message

print score
```

Comment: The code inside the `with` block should be indented.